# How to repeat rows in dataframe based on the range of a time variable in R?

Tags: r, range

I have a df, such that a row looks like:

```
name datesemployed        university   
Kate Oct 2015 – Jan 2016  Princeton
```

What I want to do is repeat the entire row for each year in the range of variable `datesemployed`.

In this case, there would be two rows --- one for 2015, and one for 2016.

I've attempted to clean the variable first, but even having a tough time on how to do that:

```
df3<-str_split_fixed(df$datesemployed, "–", 2)
df<-cbind(df3, df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` from `tidyr` while specifying the `sep` as zero or more spaces followed by `-` and then any spaces

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     separate_rows(datesemployed,  sep="\\s*–\\s*")
#    name datesemployed university
#1 Kate      Oct 2015  Princeton
#2 Kate      Jan 2016  Princeton
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(name = "Kate", datesemployed = "Oct 2015 – Jan 2016", 
    university = "Princeton"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: is there anyway this code could be adapted if the range of time was not one year? ie, if the range of years was something like 2015-2017? Tried playing around with it but haven't found an elegant adaption

Comment: @YuNa Can you please post as a new question so that it becomes easier to understand

Comment: posted! thanks for your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61703818/repeat-row-based-on-time-range-variable-r